# Loop thru a string with numbers and symbols & push to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to loop thru a string with numbers that has a symbol inside, I want the numbers before the symbol to be pushed to an array then the symbol to another array and then get the rest of the numbers after the symbol pushed to a 3rd array.

```
 var myString = "1234*5678";

 var number1 = [];
 for (i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
     if (isNaN(myString[i]) === false) {
         var firstSet = number1.push(myString[i]);
     }
 };

 var mySymbol = [];

 for (j = number1[0]; j < myString.length; j++) {
     if (isNaN(myString[j]) === true) {
         var mathematics = mySymbol.push(myString[j])
         document.write(mySymbol[0])
     }
 };
```

when I document.write the "mySymbol" variable it gives the desired result, but when I call the "number1" variable it gives me the numbers from before and after the symbol I only want the numbers before the symbol to be pushed to the array, also how do I write the 3rd loop to get the numbers after the symbol pushed to a new array?

Comment: try `myString.split('*')`. Will probably help here.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using:

```
var myString = '1234*5678';
var resultArr = myString.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([^a-zA-Z0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/);
```

To get the string before symbol:

```
var myFirstSet = resultArr[1];
```

To get symbol:

```
var mySymbol = resultArr[2];
```

To get the string after symbol:

```
var mySecondSet = resultArr[3];
```

To convert each of these three groups into their own arrays:

```
var result = [];
resultArr
.slice(1)
.forEach(
    function(s){
        result.push(s
                    .split('')
                    .map(
                        function(n){
                            return parseInt(n) || n;
                        }
                    )
        )
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```js
var arr=[[],[],[]]
    
    index = 0

"1234*5678".split('').forEach(function(e){
    if(parseInt(e)){
       arr[index].push(e); 
    }else{
       index ++;
       arr[index++].push(e)
    }
});
document.write('First Array ' +arr[0] + '<br>');
document.write('Secont Array ' +arr[1] + '<br>');
document.write('Third Array ' +arr[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code accomplishes the goal:

```
var str = '1234*5678';
var arr = str.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|\*/g);

console.log(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hp2ohvzb/

Comment: thanks for your answer it works. But what if the special character depends on user input for example he puts a # or ! instead of * how do I write the code to work according to user input.

Comment: Update regex to `str.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|\W/g);` - http://jsfiddle.net/um4hgzh3/